# printf behaving weirdly

Tags: c, printf

I have a simple program which is supposed to print a string. But I am not getting the expected output. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the program ?

Here is my code:

```
main()
{
   char arr[] = "Test_string";
   printf("%20s"+1,arr);
   return 0;
}

output: 20s
```

Expected output is:`Test_string`

`"Test_string"` getting printed in 20 places as we are giving `"%20s"` as format specifier.

Comment: Why do you have a +1 in your printf?

Comment: What is the 'expected output'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very simple if you carefully look at your `printf` call.

Here is the prototype of [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) : `int printf(const char *format, ...);`.

`printf` expects a pointer to format string as the first argument. In your program you are passing a pointer to this string : `"20s"` and `printf` promptly prints what you are passing.

Let me explain why the pointer passed is pointing to `"20s"` and not `"%20s"`.

<strike>Quoted strings in C are interpreted as character pointers.</strike>
Character arrays which, when passed to a function, decay into a pointer.

`printf("%20s",arr);` is equivalent to :

```
const char * ptr = "%20s";
printf(ptr,arr);
```

similarly `printf("%20s"+1,arr);` is equivalent to :

```
const char * ptr = "%20s";
printf(ptr+1,arr);
```

Because you are passing `"%20s"+1`, the actual pointer which is passed to printf is pointing to a string `"20s"`.

Comment: "Quoted strings in C are interpreted as character pointers." - not at all, rather as character arrays which, when passed to a function, decay into a pointer. Also, unless being used for intializing an array, string literals are `const`, so you should not write `char * ptr = "%20s"` but `char const *ptr = "%20s"`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Completely agree with you. Updated the answer.

Comment: @H2CO3: The array elements of a string literal have type `char`, not `const char`, per C 2011 6.4.5 6. They are read-only because paragraph 7 says “If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.” However, in spite of being read-only, they do not have the `const` attribute, for legacy reasons.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am keeping my edits as is because printf expects const char *. Thanks for confirming with standard.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the +1 next to the format string

```
printf("%20s",arr);
```